# ASP.NET TextBox's OnTextChanged server event should fire some client code before going to server

Tags: asp.net, events

My UserControl has a TextBox, that is subscribed to OnTextChanged event. However, since a lots of business logic and integrations happens on server, I want to disable a form while postback is being performed with some client-side javascript and I'm not sure how to achieve it the right way.

Can I solve this with ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference?

Edit: as my question seems to be misunderstood:

TextBox is subscribed to event OnTextChanged="tb_TextChanged" which will result on client in onchange=__doPostBack('tb') so I want to inject my javascript disableForm() to onchange DOM event. I know how to implement disableForm(), the question is how to inject my javascript properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the javascript [onblur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) event and check if the field value is changed. If so, you can use jQuery like the below to disable the form elements.

To disable a form element such as a text input or a button (with a made-up id: #elm):

```
$("#elm").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

To enable a disabled form element:

```
$("#elm").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Well, this is not exactly the issue. I know how I will disable the form, but I need to do the postback as well.
TextBox is subscribed to event OnTextChanged="tb_TextChanged" which will result on client in onchange=__doPostBack('tb') so I want to inject my javascript disableForm() to onchange DOM event. The question is how to do that properly?

Comment: You can use Button1.Attributes.Add("onblur", "disableForm()");

Comment: Actually it is the "onchange" the one that I need and I was really surprised, when adding `tb.Attributes.Add("onchange", "LockForm();ShowLoadingMessage();");` on Page_Load, the __doPostBack was just appended to my javacript in DOM property "onchange", so the ting works perfectly. I would expect that ASP.NET would just override whatever is in  "onchange" with __doPostback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with some simple JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    disableFormFields = function(){
        if (document.all || document.getElementById){
            for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++){
                var el = document.forms[0].elements[i];
                if (el){
                    el.disabled = true;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onchange="disableFormFields();" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" />
```